# Can I still purchase additional site licenses for EE 1.x MSM

Tags: multi-site-manager, license, 1.x

I have a client site running on a legacy version of EE1.x, it's pretty old and they have no desire to upgrade to EE 2.x as it does the job just fine as is.

They have a MSM license associated with the site and as such can run up to 3 sites off the one install - at present they are running 3 sites but wish to add another.

This is a simple job, very much a copy/paste on the existing sites to create a new one for a slightly different target audience - however I'm not sure if I can even buy a new EE1.x MSM site license - the EE store does not appear to be happy with me trying to do so...

Does anyone know if Ellis Lab are still selling EE1.x MSM site licenses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just email them at sales@ellislab.com. It requires an "upgrade" of the MSM license I believe. Then you can add licenses. (But they can confirm or correct this information for you.)

For future reference (for anyone reading this): these types of questions are probably not well suited for StackExchange. Just shoot EllisLab an email so you can get an answer directly from the source. Both sales@ellislab.com and team@ellislab.com get to them I believe.

Comment: Cheers Erik - I did ping them an email but no reply as of yet and I wondered if anyone else had been along the same path. You're right though - prob not the ideal question for SE. :)

Comment: FYI: Transpires that the EE1.x MSM upgrade process on the EE store was borked in some fashion. I got an email from Kevin Smith to let me know that it's now fixed.